# Display a message based on MS Graph API response status (React/TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm new to React/TypeScript. I'm making a POST graph api call as follows:

```
export async function callMsGraph(id: string) {      

    const options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify({"string"})
    };

    var url = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/${id}/owners/$ref/`;
    var resp: Response;
    return fetch(url, options)
    .then(resp => {       
        return (resp.status.toString());
      });
    }
```

```
export const Comp: React.FunctionComponent = () => {  
  const [status, setStatus] = useState('');
  const [err, setError] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    callMsGraph("id")
      .then(response => setStatus(response))
      .catch(err => setError(err));
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>      
      {(() => {
        if (status === "403") {
          return (
            <div>no permission</div>
          )
        } else if (status === "400") {
          return (
            <div>already exists</div>
          )
        } else if (status === "204") {
          return (
            <div>Success</div>
          )
        }
      })()}

    </div>
  );
};
```

This works fine. status code 400 is returned in two scenarios - if already added or if an invalid group id is provided.

```
{"error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":"One or more added object references already exist for the following modified properties: 'owners'."

{"error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":"Invalid object identifier 'xxx'."
```

How do I display two different messages for these two scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

The [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API doesn't reject the return promise when a response with an HTTP Error Status Code is returned, which is why the `status` state is set and your current conditional rendering logic works.

You would just have to return the response body in your API wrapper as well and check against that value to conditionally render.

Ideally, you should make the check the response details in the `.then()` part of your wrapper code and decide whether it is a success or error.

If success, return like you are doing now.

If error, throw an error allowing the `.catch()` call in your `useEffects()` code to trigger, setting the `err` state.

If your render code, you should just check if `err` is truthy and render an error message component, otherwise render the successful response.